# Modifying an HTML string via jquery and producing another html string that reflects the changes made?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-development-server

I am trying to write a series of functions that modify a form based on the values of an array.
 My specific issue is that for my functions I am taking in a string of html. I apply that html to a div element and use jquery to make modifications to the html.

The specific types of modifications are mainly $("#target").show() and writing in some text here and there.

The problem I have is that none of my research or looking into this issue online has led me to finding a way I can then convert my modified html into a string. The condition being that I want this string to retain the changes I made from my $("#target").show() types of modifications.

Is it possible to make these types of modifications to a jquery object and then produce a string that reflects these changes in a plain string?

**UPDATE** thanks for your quick responses guys I've tried 
.html()
.innerhtml
.outerhtml and a few other methods

The main thing I'm trying to find out though is: 
I take an html string. 
Apply it to a div using .html() and modify it so that particular elements do not show. 
I then want to convert it back to an html string, so that when I apply it again, those same elements I manipulated with jquery with the .show() and .hide() methods will continue to be hidden and show.

Like I said I tried converting my modified element to html using .html and .innerhtml and when I apply it again the jquery/dynamic modifications are gone

Hopefully this makes everything easier to understand:

```
 function main_selector(notiftype,array){
   /**
   - a function that recieves a type parameter and an array that invokes
   the functions listed below
   **/
 var strings;
 strings=importhtml();
 strings=manipulateHtml(strings,notiftype,array);
 strings= elemanipulateHtml(strings,notiftype,array);
 strings=btnmanipulateHtml(strings,notiftype,array);
 writeHTML(strings);
 }

   function importHtml(   ){
   /**
   - a function that will import the html file and return it as a
     a html string for manipulation
   **/

   var htmlstrings;
          $.ajax({
                   url: "/*******",
                   global: false,
                   type: 'POST',
                   async: false,
                   success: function(result) {
                htmlstrings=result;}
          });
          return htmlstrings;
   }

 function elemanipulateHtml(htmlstring,notiftype,array){
   /**
   - a function that will accept a string of html, a type parameter
     and an array and will determine based on the type and the contents
     of the array which elements in the form are shown, and what they
     contain.
 }
```

^ my issue is that I need a way to ensure that after I have executed my $("#target").show(); type statements in elemanipulate. I can convert the modified html to a string that will retain the fact that #target is hidden. I have tried using .html and the changes aren't retained so I'm trying to find out if there is a way to do this.

Comment: Sure, there are ways to do so. What have you tried so far? Post your code, preferably in a fiddle.

Comment: Call `.html()` on the modified DOM element, that will return the HTML string.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery method `.html()` returns the HTML string of the contents of a DOM element.

```
var html_string = $("#div").html();
```